# How to check if username already exists in firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to check were the users already exists with the same username here is example

[image]

Here is my code,

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
 Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("userName").equalTo(userEnteredUserName);
```

but without the uid it works perfect, but whenever there is uid unable to check the username, Is there is anyway to check username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is expecting `userName` to be a direct field in username node and because userId is not same for everyone you cannot specify a neste path. If you remove the username node and restructure the DB as shown below, the same query should work perfectly:

```
Users
  | // remove [username] node from here
  |-userId  // userId from Firebase Auth
    |
    |-userName
    |-otherFields
```

If you want to retain existing structure then you can just check if a node with given username exists:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("userName");
```